# R How to segregate a data frame and perform a function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I've a data in the following format

```
     Id        Duration  Name
    (Numeric)  (Factor)  (Factor)

     1          2         x
     1          3         y
     1          1         z
     2          1         x
     2          2         x
```

I want to iterate over the 'id' field and for each unique id, I need to create an array from 'Name' field of the form (x,y,z) {the order is important}.

The expected output would look something like a map

```
     1 : (x,y,z)
     2 : (x,x)
```

I'm using a nested for loop to iterate over the length of the unique(Id) but i feel i'm defeating the purpose of using R.

I feel a little rusty with my understanding of the apply family of functions and although i looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/r-how-to-call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-argum) and specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783860/loop-over-unique-values-r) but the challenge in using lapply also is the difference in data types of the columns.

Do let me know if someone can suggest a better alternative than using for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` as the OP's initial dataset seems to be `tbl` class.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Id) %>%
     summarise(val = toString(Name))
#     Id     val
#   (int)   (chr)
#1     1 x, y, z
#2     2    x, x
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Duration = 
 structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("x", "y", 
    "z"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", "Duration", "Name"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))
```

Comment: I've run the code in the following format : df1 %>% group_by(df1$id) %>% summarise(val = toString(df1$Name))                                                      I'm getting the following exception on running this **Error: invalid subscript type 'double'**

Comment: @hbabbar I am not getting any error.  I updated with the dataset used.  Can you update your post with the dput output of the example showed.  I am using `dplyr_0.4.3` on `R 3.2.3`

Comment: In case your data is not pre-ordered, you will want to insert an arrange(Name) before group_by() in the above code.

Comment: @akrun : Maybe the sample data that i was showing doesnt capture the missing values in my original dataset and the format that i have. And my data is pre ordered still i get the same error.

Comment: @hbabbar Can you update the post with the `dput` of  a small example that gives the error.  It would be easier to fix in that way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
out <- dt[, list(res = paste(Name, collapse = ',')), by = Id]
```